# How can I display only My account link in top links in magento?

Tags: magento, header

I have displayed all links in footer and i want to display My account link only in header

So how can i do that.

Should i use static block from cms pages or block from xml file?

Can anyone please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Want you to add the links of my account section???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to add "My Account" link
goto **app/design/frontend/default(or your theme package)/(theme folder)/page/html/header.phtml**.
In this file you can add your custom 'li' tag and can put a link for "My Account" as Controller moves it to My Account PAGE.

One more way here for you :)

Open theme/layout/customer.xml file and then modify the section that shows customer links on all pages, to include a link home and also a link to other customer service pages that you have deemed necessary, e.g. ‘returns’ (if you get a lot of those enquiries...).

```
<default>

    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Home</label><url></url><title>Home</title><prepare>true</prepare><urlParams/><position>5</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>94</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Deliveries</label><url>deliveries</url><title>Deliveries</title><prepare>true</prepare><urlParams/><position>95</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Returns</label><url>returns</url><title>Returns</title><prepare>true</prepare><urlParams/><position>96</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Contact Us</label><url>contacts</url><title>Contact Us</title><prepare>true</prepare><urlParams/><position>97</position></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 3):

> **Option 1:**

The layout files are used to display links in the top.links block. You can remove them in the relevant xml files, and leave everything else as is, e.g. in `checkout.xml` you have something like:

```
 <default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
            <action method="addCartLink"></action>
            <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
    </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

If you remove the block then they would no longer show these two links in the top.links block.

> **Option 2:**

The alternative is, as you say, to create a cms block and include this in your header instead. To include a cms block in a template file you can use

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('toplinksblock')->toHtml() ?>
```

Or if you want to use the layout system use this in the layout file:

```
<reference name="footer">
  <block type="cms/block" name="sample_links">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>sample_links</block_id></action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

then this in the template file:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sample_links') ?>
```

> **Option 3:**

Or just edit `top.links.phtml`.